# SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting while in hosting

Tags: php, email, smtp

While running the PHPMailer in localhost mail will be sending but while hosting the PHPMailer shows the error as SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting. please help me.

here is my code

```
 <?php
//include PHPMailerAutoload.php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'mail@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = 'password';

$mail->setFrom('mail@gmail.com', 'mail');
$mail->addAddress('mail@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = 'SMTP email test';
$mail->Body = 'Thanks for commenting';


if ($mail->send())
    echo "mail is sent";
else
    echo $mail->ErrorInfo;
?>
```

Comment: So what does your php error log file say?

Comment: Enable debug mode to verbose errors

Comment: enable debug mode and you can tail it, also dont forget to allow open connection to spesific port that you using

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's make it clearly :

- Make sure your SMTP Port code is same with SMPT port in your host
- Auth to your account is not wrong
- Check phpmailer class are success to call like `vardump or something else`

Sample of my Code :

```
  require(https://example.com/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
  require(https://example.com/class.phpmailer.php');
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'mail.example.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;

  $mail->Username = 'customer_service@example.com'; 
  $mail->Password = 'blablabla'; 

  $mail->From = 'customer_service@example.com';
  $mail->setFrom('customer_service@example.com', 'My Cool Website');

  $mail->AddAddress('recipient@destination.com', 'Recipient Full Name');
  $mail->WordWrap = 70;

  $mail->Subject = 'PHP Mailer';
  $mail->Body = 'Awesome';

  $mail->IsHTML(TRUE);
```